from where the child process will get informations about other variables that are before the fork()?
in my case i have a code where there are mentioned many fork() (8 times) functions so many child processes are going to be created , so let's imagine the every fork() is related to its variable like this :
pid1=fork(), pid2=fork(), pid3=fork() ... 

and at the beginning of the code all variables (pid1,...,pid8 got the value of 0) , now my question is how can the pid2 know the value of the variable pid1 knowing that fork()=pid1 is mentioned before pid2=fork()? is it gonna take it from the variables that are declared in the top (pid1=0,pid2=0,...,pid8=0) or is it gonna take it from the parent process which is pid1 (but pid1 gets 0 as return from the pid1=fork()), can someone explain please ?
i tried the getpid() and getppid() functions and i got the tree structure but i still need to know from where the child process gets the values of other variables that are declared before the fork()

The child process inherits a copy of the parent's memory at the time of the fork, so pid1 in the child will have the same value as it had in the parent just before the fork. Note that fork() returns different values for the parent and child, so for pid1=fork(); the value of the pid1 variable will be changed to different values in the parent and child after that call to fork().

The comma operator evaluates its arguments left to right. So pid2=fork() happens after pid1=fork(). So the memory that's copied by the second fork() has the new value of pid1 in it.

A fork() call returns twice, once in the parent and once in the child. At that point, program memory and execution context, including the values of all variables, look the same in both processes, except that the fork() return values differ, and except for the details documented on the fork() manual page.

After the first fork, there are 2 processes.  In one of them (call it A), pid1 is zero, and in the other (call it B) it is non-zero.  When A calls pid2=fork(), a process will be created in which pid1 is zero.  When B calls pid2=fork(), a process will be created in which pid1 is non-zero.
